# How to properly remove # comments in a semantic .n3 file without affecting the rest of the #s?

Tags: c#, regex, code-cleanup, n3

I'm dealing with cleaning semantic .n3 and rdf files manually from comments and compacting and pretty printing those ones with Regex in C#.

However `#` is a very common character in semantic files for describing resources.

Example code:

```
#Processed by Id: cwm.py,v 1.197 2007/12/13 15:38:39 syosi Exp 
        #    using base http://www.prodigi.eu/instances

#  Notation3 generation by
#       notation3.py,v 1.200 2007/12/11 21:18:08 syosi Exp

#   Base was: http://www.prodigi.eu/instances
     @prefix : </ac-schema#> .
    @prefix ins: </instances#> .
    @prefix olanet: <http://www.ibermaticaindustria.com/soluciones/planta-mes-olanet#> .
    @prefix plm: <http://hms.ifw.uni-hannover.de/#> .
    @prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .

    ins:everyone     a <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Group>;
         :canSee ins:public;
         rdfs:member <http://127.0.0.1/OslcOlanetProvider/api/producer/01>,

[...]
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'without affecting rest of the slashes' ?

Comment: This is a slash `/`, did you mean a `#` hash?

Comment: Yes, hash #. In a resource, sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
^\s*#.*$
```

and replace by empty

Assuming that, A comment will start with a #, or it may only be preceded by 
\r or \n or \t or \f \v or space

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/apIT0O/5)

Read each file as string and call the following method and write in the file again.

Sample Code:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
..........
...........
    public String removeHash(String input)
    {
        string pattern = @"^\s*#.*$";
        string substitution = @"";

        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, options);
        string result = regex.Replace(input, substitution);
        return result;
    }
```